# DER encoded RSA public key (OCTET STRING )

Tags: java, android, rsa, der

We are trying to create a RSA public key which should be octet string and then we need to make it DER encoded.

We are trying to create a key pair using below code:

```
public static KeyPair getRSAKeyPair() throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
    g.initialize(2048);
    return g.generateKeyPair();
```

}

and then getting public key from it using below code

```
PublicKey publicKey1 =  keyPair.getPublic();
byte[] pubkey =  publicKey1.getEncoded();
```

It seems public key getting fetched in above code are DER encoded binary string.

Queries:

1. How can I change the above code so that it creates an octet string.
2. How can I make it DER encoded.

Comment: Don't specify a provider unless you have a good reason for doing so. It probably only makes your code non-portable.

Answer (score 3):

It *is* an octet string; "octet string" is another term for "byte array".

And it is already DER encoded, because `getEncoded` normally returns a DER encoded `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. Try `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <file>` on it.